# Class containing vector of classes

Tags: c++, class, c++11, object, vector

I have defined two classes :

```
class Group
{
  public:
    Group ( void );
    bool addStudent ( const Student & X );
    void printAll( void ) const;

  protected:
    vector<Student> vectorOfStudents;
};
//-----------------------------------------------
class Student
{
   public:
     Student ( string name, int age );
     void printAtributes ( void );

   protected:
     string                    nameOfStudent;
     int                       ageOfStudent;
};
```

I'm creating objects and storing them in Group object to vector but i have problem when i want to print them :

```
void Group::printAll ( void ) const
{
  for ( const auto &  student : vectorOfStudents )
  {
    student . printAtributes (  ); // Line 54
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

Here is the function which should call and print name of student every time :

```
void Student::printAtributes ( void )
{
  cout << "name: " << nameOfStudent << " | " << "age: " << ageOfStudent<< endl;
}
```

Gives me this error :

```
54:33: error: passing ‘const Student’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void Student::printAtributes()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
     student . printAtributes (  );
```

Comment: Does that still happen if you don't store the vector in a class? Please take the habit first extracting a minimal but complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
void printAtributes ( void );
```

to

```
void printAtributes ( void ) const;
                          // ^^^^^
```

As you're explicitly requiring it from a const reference

```
for ( const auto &  student : vectorOfStudents )
   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

the function must be declared as being callable from a `const` reference.

Comment: Oh thanks i had it like that before but it was still giving me errors but i forgot to change it in class as well.

Comment: And the explicit `const` is required, since `std::begin()` on a `const std::vector<T>` yields a `const_iterator`.